# visual studio 2012 настройка

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Как включить поддержку стандарта С99 в visual studio 2012?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как включить поддержку стандарта компилятором, который не поддерживает этот стандарт? Ответ очевиден: никак. Правьте исходники или переходите на свежую версию студии.

Comment: Можно обходным манёвром: [компилировать проект как C++](http://jaysonknight.com/blog/archive/2013/01/18/how-to-compile-iso-c-99-code-in-visual-studio.aspx) :)

Comment: так и сделал компилирую как с++

Comment: А что именно Вы хотите получить от `c99`?

Comment: программа не компилируется без поддержки этого стандарта